# Get class by name

Tags: swift, metaprogramming

Can I get a class by its name? For example:

```
class Foo {

}

class Bar {

}

let x = "Foo"
classByString(x) // need to return Foo
```

I want to use metaprogramming to reduce code maintenance.

Comment: Create constant file and write all classname with constant variable in it, you need to write once and use any time.

Comment: @Jacky Thank, but I would need zero maintenance when to add a new class, to avoid forgetting

Comment: @Jacky I can make it in Ruby and Python, then I would like to know if it is possible in Swift

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't possible. You might be able to get similar behavior if you work only with objective-c (NSObject) types. If you can offer a more complete example of what this is trying to accomplish there may be better alternatives available within swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `NSClassFromString`:

```
if let anyObj : AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("MyAppName.MySwiftClassFoo") {
   //call Foo
} else {
   //call Bar
}
```